# How to create a 360 video from fisheye projection

Tags: javascript, video, three.js, 360-panorama

I am trying to render a 360 video from a 360 fisheye projection, using Three.js (Just an example to clear up what type of projection this is: http://www.huwpenson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/FISHEYE-15.jpg)

Now, I have been successfully rendering 360 videos from an equiangular projection. But I can't figure out how to set the projection type on Three.js

Here is my base code for the 360 video player:

```
var container, mesh;

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
            geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );

            var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
            video.width = 640;
            video.height = 360;
            video.autoplay = true;
            video.loop = true;
            video.src = "textures/pano.webm";

            var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
            texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

            var material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            scene.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```